# How to send push notification on android device using Amazon Web Service SNS in c#?

Tags: c#, amazon-sns

I want sample project or a code in C# for sending sample notification.
I have searched online for sample code for the AWS SNS in C# but not getting any useful resource. 
And AWS SNS API's information for sending notification will also be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bit old, but for what it's worth: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-sns-android.html